# the right excerise progragram for me?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, strength, nutrition, programs

I'm 23 years old 1.68~1.7 meter and I have spent the past 16 years in a sedentary lifestyle. Most of my body isn't fat with the exception of my belly which is 107 centimeters. What is the best program to follow to lose this extra weight as fast as possible, and, in the same time I don't not gain a lot of muscles (I'm pleased with my current "shape")?

Also, is exercise to boost the speed and strength of my muscles?
And, what nutrient plan should I follow?

*note: it would be better if the program doesn't include exercises dependent on machines or dimples, as there is no  GYM in my place of residence.

Answer (score 1):

Losing weight does have a correlation with working out/lifting.

The most important thing is your diet, not the program. The program is 30%-40% of weight loss, while your diet is the 60-70%.

What you put in your body becomes your body. If you eat clean, your body will be clean (cut, slim, lean). Working out tones the body to lift the weight that you want, therefore resulting in more muscle mass.

If you are pleased with your shape, then do some cardio. Such as running, jumping jacks, running in place, step-ups (use stairs outside or at a playground). But honestly, to lose weight in a healthy manner, you want to fix your diet.

I'm a bit like you. I'm 1.74m (5ft 7in) tall and my belly was well really fat (due to beer). I didn't lose much "weight" since I am lifting but I lost a lot of my beer belly in 1 month. http://bodyspace.bodybuilding.com/progress-photos/Nifear4

Here is my progress.